# grpc connection management have mismatched number of connections

Tags: grpc

We have a project that is built on bi-directional grpc client/server in C++. Client makes only one connection to the server. Server will have multiple clients.
Via "netstat" command, server side shows multiple established connections from the same client, but client only has one active connection to this server at the time.

Following is one example:

on server side:

netstat -an|grep "port"|grep "clientip"

tcp6       0      0 serverip:port        clientip:61501     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       0      0 serverip:port        clientip:60241     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       0      0 serverip:port        clientip:54173     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       0      0 serverip:port        clientip:48677     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       0      0 serverip:port        clientip:53149     ESTABLISHED

while on client side:

netstat -an|grep "serverip"

tcp6       0      0 clientip:53149     serverip:port        ESTABLISHED

This seems that the server side can not remove the stale connections.
The consequence of this is that server is possible to exceed the max connection limit, which will cause other issues.

Is anyone seeing the same symptoms? Is there any suggestions in terms of grpc connection management?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try enabling keepalives on your connections?

Comment: thanks. We tried that before but does not help. Now we are looking at app level close client code. App level closes the client if has connection errors. One hypothesis is that when multiple threads keep closing the client channel when having the connection errors (to the same server), it may result in all client connections in a state that not able to be acked in time. We pushed the fix out last week. Will update this thread if this is proved. Thanks!